# SQL Multi-Table Join with SUM

Tags: sql, join, sum

Hi I'm a beginner with SQL and have a problem.

I have the following 5 tables:

**Branch** (Name, City),
**Employee** (EmpNo, Name, Branch),
**Customer** (CustNo, Name, EmpNo),
**AccountDetails** (AccNo, CustNo),
**Account** (AccNo, Balance)

Employees are joined to a single Branch via the Employee Branch attribute.
Customers are joined to a single Employee via the EmpNo attribute.

Each customer can have many Accounts, and each Account can have several customers (so a shared account is allowed) - hence I made an intersection entity (AccountDetails).

I want to SUM the total Balance for each Branch - the problem I get is that my total is double counting i.e. as many customers can share an account my code will count each Customers accounts, even though it is referring to the same AccNo - so the AccNo and accompanying Balance is counted over and over again, depending on how many Customers are sharing an account, so if 2 customers share an Account then the Balance will be counted twice.

```
select sum(a.balance), a.accno, b.name
from branch b, bankemployee e, customer c, accountdetails d, account a
where b.name = e.branch
and e.empno = c.empno
and c.custno = d.custno
and d.accno = a.accno
group by a.accno, b.name
```

I have used DISTINCT e.g. d.accno IN (select distinct accno from accountDetails) but to no avail, it still double counts.

I put a Branch attribute in the Account table but I don't want to do it that way if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Why are you joining to customer, accountdetails, and bankemployee exactly?  You don't seem to use columns from them.

Comment: And when multiple customers share an account that has employees at different branches, what should be done?  Your data model has some problems.  Notably, it seems strange that a customer is attached to a bank employee directly.

Comment: @Aushin could you elaborate on what you mean? Thanks

Comment: @GordonLinoff I would say the way it is designed is that the customers must be at the same branch to have an account, although this is not specified. And yes it doesn't make much sense that the customer is attached to a bank employee directly rather than to a specific branch, however sadly this is not something I can change as a I was given the relational schema for the database. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It uses a subquery to get only one customer's info for each account.  This is not ideal, but based on your db structure it should work:

```
select sum(accts.balance), accts.accno, b.name
from branch b inner join bankemployee e on b.name = e.branch
inner join customer c on e.empno = c.empno
inner join (select a.accno, a.balance, max(b.custno) as custMax from account as a
inner join accountdetails as b on a.accno=b.accno
 group by a.accno,a.balance) as accts on c.custno=accts.custMax
group by accts.accno, b.name
```

Comment: +1 . . . I don't particularly like this solution, but it seems to be about the best with this data model.

Comment: @jle I use a different style of syntax so have not been able to convert it over exactly. Can you explain the reason behind max(b.custno)? Thanks

Comment: Max of customer number will get a single customer number (doesn't really matter which one for your purposes) for each account number.

Comment: And just FYI, the inner joins are equivalent to the where clauses in your queries